# IE8 Compatibility issue

Tags: jquery, prado, ie-compatibility-mode

I want only IE8 to work with compatibility mode. But I couldn't do it by using the first way below:

**First way:** (It doesn't work)

```
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <com:TMetaTag HttpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" Content="IE=EmulateIE7" />  
    <![endif]-->
```

**Second way:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

     if($j.browser.msie && $j.browser.version == "8.0")
     {
         alert("<com:TMetaTag HttpEquiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" Content=\"IE=EmulateIE7\" /> ");
     }

</script>
```

Now I am trying to echo the meta tag by using jquery like above. But I don't know how to do that? So I alert it to show you the problem clearly.

**Note:** I am using a php framework named by prado. So the tag element is a little bit different like (`<com:TMetaTag...`)

Comment: why on earth would you want it to use compatibility mode?

Comment: Because IE8 has some design problems and unfortunately to run it compability mode is the easist way for now. Thanks for answer.

Comment: try using diff rendering mode 
http://firstblog-jc.blogspot.com/2011/02/ie-rendering-modes.html

Answer (score 2):

IE8 in compatibility mode is going to recognize as IE7.

Try

`<!--[if lte IE 8]>`

Comment: Actually this is the first way I have been tried before. The meta inside that tag is working for all IE versions. I think this is somehow related PRADO. Because I wrapped these meta tags not like <head></head> . It is <com:THead></com:THead>. Maybe it behaves different because of that but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript, you would use the

```
document.write()
```

Method to write directly into the HTML.

Edit: Didn't see you were using JQuery.  This is probably a safer way of doing things:

```
$("head").append('<com:TMetaTag HttpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" Content="IE=EmulateIE7" />')
```